# redirecting to another controller with onchange

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
<th>@Html.DropDownList("Tables", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "A", Value = "Admin/Index"},
    new SelectListItem { Text = "B", Value = "Admin/Index"}
}, "WWW",new { @onchange="location=this.value" })</th>
```

This code only works for 1st time, later instead redirect to controller "Admin/Index" it starts to copy itself.So I have address like this

```
localhost/Admin/Admin/Index instead of localhost/Admin/Index
```

I have also tried, but same effect

```
@onchange="document.href.location=this.value
@onchange="window.href.location=this.value
```

How to make correct js, so redirecting would work all the time.

Comment: Not sure, but try this:  `@Url.Content("Index","Admin")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a slash to the values, so it always starts from the root:

```
<th>@Html.DropDownList("Tables", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "A", Value = "/Admin/Index"},
    new SelectListItem { Text = "B", Value = "/Admin/Index"}
}, "WWW",new { @onchange="location=this.value" })</th>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an absolute instead of a relative path.  I'd suggest adding `/` in front of the redirect URL, like this:

```
new { @onchange="location='/' + this.value" })
```

---

The only problem with this approach is, if you ever deploy to a server where your application isn't at the root (eg, like `http://myserver/myapp/Admin/Index`), then the link will be incorrect (ie, it will point to `http://myserver/Admin/Index`).  For that reason, it's better to use the `Url.Action` helper:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Tables", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "A", Value = Url.Action("Index", "Admin") },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "B", Value = Url.Action("Index", "Admin") }
}, "WWW",new { @onchange="location=this.value" })
```

This will ensure the correct URL regardless of the environment.